# Unable to run a uwsgi-nginx-flask container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

To set up a `uwsgi-nginx-flask` server with a `uwsgi.ini` file, I am using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/) image.
On running the container after building the image I get an error:

`*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***`

My project directory structure looks likes:

```
|-- Dockerfile
|-- docker-compose.yml
`-- test-app
    |-- app.py
    `-- uwsgi.ini
```

The `uwsgi.ini` and Dockerfile looks as follows:

`[uwsgi]
module = test-app.app
callable = app`

`COPY  ./test-app/ /app/test-app/
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:/app/
RUN mv test-app/uwsgi.ini ./uwsgi.ini`

How do I successfully run the container?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been quite a while. I honestly don't remember.